# R: Bootstrap percentile confidence interval

Tags: r, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

```
library(boot)
set.seed(1)
x=sample(0:1000,1000)
y=function(u,i) sum(x[i])
o=boot(x,y,1000)
theta1=NULL
theta1=cbind(theta1,o$t)
b=theta1[order(theta1)]
bp1=c(b[25], b[975])
ci=boot.ci(o,type="perc")
```

I am using two method to construct bootstrap percentile confidence interval but I got two different answer.

```
bp1=c(b[25], b[975]) get (480474,517834)
```

while `ci=boot.ci(o,type="perc")` get (480476, 517837 )

How does the boot.ci construct the percentile interval?

Comment: what packages are `boot` and `boot.ci` from?

Comment: it come from library(boot)

Answer (score 4):

By calling the function by itself `boot.ci`, the script appears.  You can then see that the percentile CI is calculated using the function `perc.ci` (around line 70).  On [Github](https://github.com/cran/boot/blob/master/R/bootfuns.q), you can get the package script. Looking for the `perc.ci` function, your find this:

```
perc.ci <- function(t, conf = 0.95, hinv = function(t) t)
  #
  #  Bootstrap Percentile Confidence Interval Method
  #
{
  alpha <- (1+c(-conf,conf))/2
  qq <- norm.inter(t,alpha)
  cbind(conf,matrix(qq[,1L],ncol=2L),matrix(hinv(qq[,2]),ncol=2L))
}
```

Which then leads to the `norm.inter` function which seems to be the one creating the vector for extracting the percentiles.  Looking for this function in the same Github script tel us:

> Interpolation on the normal quantile scale.  For a non-integer
>     order statistic this function interpolates between the surrounding
>     order statistics using the normal quantile scale.  See equation
>     5.8 of Davison and Hinkley (1997)

So it seems it's using interpolation from a normal distribution explaining why it's different from your totally empirical solution.

Answer (score 1):

The standard interval using basic boostrap I always use is:

```
est <- est.from.bootstrap
basic.bs <- c(2*est-quantile(bootstrap.vector, prob=0.975), 2*est -
quantile(bootstrap.vector, prob=0.025)
```

You can also just use the normal bootstrap interval given by:

```
est <- est.from.bootstrap
bs.interval <-c(est + sd(bootstrap.vector)*qnorm(0.025), est +
sd(bootstrap.vector)*qnorm(0.975)
```

However you can also use just the normal percentile method:

```
est <- est.from.bootstrap
perc <- c(quantile(bootstrap.vector, prob=0.025), quantile(bootstrap.vector, 
prob=0.075)
```